# Hadoop Hbase Access denied exception

Tags: java, jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix, apache-ranger

I want to access phoenix tables which is synced to Hbase tables. I wrote some jdbc code to access the data from Phoenix tables but i am getting access denied exception because of ranger policies enabled.

```
Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:phoenix:abc1,abc2,abc3:2181:/hbase-unsecure","landing", "password");
System.out.println("Got connection !!!");
ResultSet rst = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from EMP");
```

I get the error message as :

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient permissions for user ‘saurav_bilung',action: scannerOpen, tableName:SYSTEM.STATS, family:0, column: GUIDE_POSTS_ROW_COUNT
    at org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.authorizeAccess(RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.java:521)
    at org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.preScannerOpen(RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.java:911)
    at org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.preScannerOpen(RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.java:855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost$50.call(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost$RegionOperation.call(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.execOperation(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.execOperationWithResult(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.preScannerOpen(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:2352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:167)
```

"landing" user has been given permission to perform all tasks through ranger but still I get error message as "insufficient privileges". I want to create connection as "landing" user. Need help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your error message, it seems to be that it's trying to authenticate for your user "saurav_bilung" instead of the "landing" user. When you spark-submit or run your code, are you sudo-ing as the "landing" user?
Also, make sure that your user and "landing" have access to the SYSTEM.STATS table. Let me know how that goes

Comment: The issue was with configuration. After configuring Apache ranger authentication with LDAP and AD and also by doing what you said the issue got resolved. Apache Ranger was new to me at that time so i was fumbling with it. The issue is resolved now. Thank you for your answer.